# SetterBar is too long. How to set option of ControlType in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

For example

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1}, ControlType -> SetterBar]
```

will have a long setterbar, I want it wrap to several lines. The `Appearance->"Row"` option of `SetterBar` seems does the job.

But how to set Appearance of SetterBar in Manipulate?

Comment: The `ControlType` and `Appearance` go inside the control definition: `Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, ControlType -> SetterBar, Appearance -> "Row"}]`

Comment: You could also use `Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Row"}, ControlType -> SetterBar]`

Comment: Or `Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, SetterBar, Appearance -> "Row"}]`.

Comment: As an alternative: `Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, SetterBar, 
  Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {4, Automatic}}]`

Comment: Thank you so much @Karsten7. Now the buttons are aligned. However, they become truly one bar without delimit lines for each button! I think I can ask no more, life is not perfect : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, SetterBar, Appearance -> "Row"}]
```

[image: setterbar]

#### Update

If you don't like the look of the "Row" layout and actually want a grid-like layout, you can write

```
Manipulate[i,
  {i, 1, 100, 1, SetterBar, Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 20}}]
```

[image: setterbar]

However, note how this layout affects the look of the buttons and the label placement.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg. There is one more issue. Why the first row and second row are not aligned? Look at "1" and "26", that is ugly.

Comment: @matheorem. It's deliberate. It's the way Mathematica likes to show that what might be mistaken for a grid of elements is really a long row that has been broken up.

Comment: Hey, m_goldberg. You must be using Mac system. right? On windows, it looks like this http://pasteboard.co/aqSU7DbTl.png , no delimit !! Ugly than yours. This is unfair : (  and this is what I communicated with Karsten 7. to seek a better looking.

Comment: @matheorem. Yes, I run Mathematica on OS X.

Comment: Mac is more beautiful on this. Thanks for showing this : )

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[i, 
 {i, 1, 100, 1, Style[Row[Setter[Dynamic[i], #] & /@ Range @@ #2], LineIndent -> 0] &}]
```

[image: perfectOut]

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing `Setter`, Karsten 7. I figure out a better looking button array `Manipulate[i, {i, 1, 100, 1, Grid[Partition[(Setter[Dynamic[i], #] & /@ Range[#2[[2]]]), 20],  Spacings -> {0.5, 0.5}] &}]` : )

Comment: One more issue. I am unable to figure out what does `#2` really mean. For example, How to do with this `Manipulate[i,{i,List}]`? I tried `#1` and others, all failed

Comment: @matheorem `#2` grabs the range of `i`. For this example it's `{1,100,1}`. I edited the answer, because `Range @@ #2` might be more intuitive than `Range[#2[[2]]]`. Try `Manipulate[i, {{i, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, Row[Setter[Dynamic[i], #] & /@ Flatten[#2]] &}]`

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.